# I'd like to answer multiple mails in my Mac with the same message

Tags: shortcuts, apple-mail

I need to answer multiple emails easily, just selecting them then clicking some button (I don't think it's possible to do it "normally"). The email to answer with contains links embedded.

I found this post from 10 years ago: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2604616

But it seems too complicated to me. I tried to use the app "shortcuts" and I didn't find any solution (I'm not an expert). So I thought my best option would then be to select all the messages, click "open", then use a combination of shortcuts: "reply" (command + r), paste (command + v), then "send" (shift + command + d). My main email account is AOL.

Do you think there would be an easier way to find this?

Thanks!

I found a script, but the solution seems too complicated. The other option it's time consuming (I need to answer about 100 emails with the same answer). The answer contains links so it's not only plain text.

Comment: What is your email app? Have you tried [this](https://ar.al/1136/)?

Comment: It's the default Mail App in Mac. I didn't try that script as I'm not familiar with terminal..